# PHPUnit code coverage reporting 0/0

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

I have a single class, and a single test file for that class. However, when I run PHPUnit I get this:

```
PHPUnit 4.0.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.

......

Time: 1.14 seconds, Memory: 17.25Mb

OK (6 tests, 6 assertions)


Code Coverage Report:  
  2014-03-12 15:47:58  

 Summary:              
  Classes:        (0/0)
  Methods:        (0/0)
  Lines:          (0/0)
```

What's going on?

**Edit**: Interestingly, outputting as php works (ie phpunit --coverage-php). It just seems like html and text don't.

**Edit again:** It seems like it's being caused by an include I have in the test class, specifically I am doing:

```
require_once('vfsStream/vfsStream.php');
```

I did find this [github issue](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/issues/107) but that seems to be on Windows and I'm not sure how it helps me fix my problem.

Comment: That looks like 100% coverage as far as I'm concerned :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not a good solution imo, but I fixed this by copying vfsStream to my project's directory and including it that way.